# Why is there difference between XSD tool and WSDL generator, output is not the same

Tags: xml, web-services, xsd

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://test/qualified/attribute/v1" 
    xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified" 
    targetNamespace="http://test/qualified/attribute/v1" 
    id="TestQualifiedAttribute" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Test">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" 
                    maxOccurs="1" 
                    fixed="FixedValue1" 
                    name="TestFixedElement">
          <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:maxLength value="255" />
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" 
                    maxOccurs="1" 
                    name="TestElement">
          <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:maxLength value="50" />
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Having this xsd above I injected it into WSDL document and converted it into class using xsd.exe tool. Situation is that:

- WSDL document output qualified attributes(xmlns) in Test inner elements
- Generated class(using xsd.exe) output elements without qualified attributes(xmlns), xmlns is present on Test element only

So now i can't serialize the `Test element` which was produced by the WSDL, using the generated `Test class` from xsd.exe

if I understood correctly the `elementFormDefault = qualified`, WSDL generator does good output, where xsd.exe is doing it wrong... so how can i fix it, should I modify XSD to output correctly with explicitly defining xmlns on inner elements?

*I will provide the WSDL and xsd.exe generated classes if it is needed*

XSD.exe output:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://test/qualified/attribute/v1")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://test/qualified/attribute/v1", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class Test {

    private string testFixedElementField;

    private string testElementField;

    public Test() {
        this.testFixedElementField = "FixedValue1";
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string TestFixedElement {
        get {
            return this.testFixedElementField;
        }
        set {
            this.testFixedElementField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string TestElement {
        get {
            return this.testElementField;
        }
        set {
            this.testElementField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

WSDL output:

```
/// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.6.1064.2")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://test/qualified/attribute/v1")]
    public partial class Test : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

        private string testFixedElementField;

        private string testElementField;

        public Test() {
            this.testFixedElementField = "FixedValue1";
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
        public string TestFixedElement {
            get {
                return this.testFixedElementField;
            }
            set {
                this.testFixedElementField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("TestFixedElement");
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=1)]
        public string TestElement {
            get {
                return this.testElementField;
            }
            set {
                this.testElementField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("TestElement");
            }
        }

        public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
            System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
            if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
                propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It might be worthwhile to show at least a partial example of the two different styles of Test elements.  As it is, it's impossible to tell whether you have a problem on your hands, or just some unnecessary and harmless extra namespace declarations.

Comment: I added the generated classes from xsd.exe and WSDL. Well i believe the serializer should be able to transform them vice-versa, but as i tested... it proved me that i am wrong...

Comment: The generated classes are different because they are generated by different tools: xsd.exe vs. svcutil.exe (which is what seems to have been used in the latter case). If I got it right, do a quick search on xsd.exe vs. svcutil.exe. The binding style in your WSDL may also have an impact on what gets generated, so you should post it, too.

Comment: From your description, it looks as if the difference between the Test elements generated by the two tools is the presence or absence of namespace declarations; that's why I wanted to see the Test elements.  (Your description says they do or don't generate "qualified attributes", which would however have nothing whatever to do with elementFormDefault.)  Good luck with this.